# Compiling with gcc and debugging with greenhills debugger

Tags: gcc, greenhills

I am a newbie to debugging. I compiled my project with gcc and i am trying to debug it with a greenhills debugger. when i try to debug it, i get an error "unreadable memory" in greenhills.
Anyone know why and how to fix this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to translate the dwarf debug information generated by gcc to a debug format that Multi understands.

Ps, I think the converter costs money!